ODBC randomly can't connect to database server
The first time this happened, I assumed it was something odd with our setup or with or with the pgodbc connection, but when it happened with another client, connecting to MS-SQL, I decided to post the question and answer.
Platform: Windows 10
Front end: App built on MS-Access
Back end: MS-SQL or PGSQL
Connection: ODBC
In both cases no changes had been made to the systems for some time.
Clients started to randomly fail to connect.
The prevailing wisdom around the office became "Reboot twice and it will start working."
In practice, it might start working after the first, second, or third reboot.

My experience with Access --> ODBC --> Backend is it times out the connection. I tried the 'fixes' from searching on 'ODBC timeout', none really worked. In my case just having the user logout out of their Windows session and back in worked. One of many reasons I gave up on Windows.

We found that
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew

would sometimes restore the connection.
The connections that failed had been assigned IP6 addresses.
Turning off IP6 on all clients resolved the issue.
Seems unlikely that we'll ever need that many clients on the LAN.
When the second client had a similar issue with randomly failing to connect to SQL, disabling IP6 resolved the issue again and made me look like a genius.
